# Android Firebase Unity have error: Gradle failed to fetch dependencies and Resolution failed , DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I need some help.
I cannot use firebase in android platform. I have an error when Resolve Android Resolver.
I could not find any solution to my problem.
how I can solve this problem. you can help me or you know who can help me

My Software Config:

```
Firebase Unity SDK 5.2.0
Android NDK r13b
Android SDK Full Update
JDK 8u181
JRE 8u181
Windows 7
Unity 2018.2.1f1
```

Unity [LogFile](https://ufile.io/6g908)

Unity Error:

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\TestFireBaseUnity\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b "C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\TestFireBaseUnity\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" --no-daemon "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Android_SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\TestFireBaseUnity\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/Users/Arman/Desktop/TestFireBaseUnity/Assets/Firebase/m2repository" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1;com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:5.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:5.2.0"'
stdout:
Unzipping C:\Users\Arman\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju\gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip to C:\Users\Arman\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju

stderr:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll()
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__2(Result)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete()
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:Update(CommandLineDialog)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:Update()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

[Image of Gradle failed to fetch dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5eAX.png)

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:5.2.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:5.2.0


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey4:<>m__1(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll()
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__2(Result)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete()
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:Update(CommandLineDialog)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:Update()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

[Image of Error Resolution failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0c2E.png)

Android Resolver Have Error Too:

[Image of Android Resolver Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXChv.png)

[Image of Resolver Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c9yk.png)

Error in Device Monitor:

```
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.2.0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initialize
```

[Image of Monitor Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peRdJ.png)

Download [Source](https://ufile.io/vkwym)

**[SOLVED MY PROBLEM]**

My problem was the version of the Android SDK build-tools and tools version.

**The Android SDK was updated, but in the build-tools directory , there was an old directory called "android-4.2.2" that solved the problem by removing it.**

**I also downgraded the Android SDK tools version from 26.1.1 to 25.2.5**

Answer (score 4):

Try to install Google Play Resolver (https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver). Here are the steps:

1. Download the unity package inside the repository. Don't download the release version, they are outdated. I downloaded it here https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/play-services-resolver-1.2.80.0.unitypackage
2. After imported the package, go to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Update
3. After everything updated open `Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android > Settings`. I checked these settings
   [image]
4. Run `Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android > Force Update`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Gradle failed to fetch dependencies (4.2.0)](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/83)

Comment: Thanks but not work to me. my Firebase Unity SDK 5.2.0 but i have still problem

Comment: @Arman did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue with the version 5.4.0 of Firebase